# Create flag if ID maps to multiple other IDs within a window

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a flag that shows which `id1` values have a duplicate mapping to `id2` over an arbitrary window `n` (`n = 2` in the example below). For example, given this DataFrame:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[("2010-03-10", "A", "X"),
 ("2010-03-10", "A", "Y"),
 ("2010-03-10", "B", "Z"),
 ("2010-04-10", "A", "X"),
 ("2010-04-10", "A", "Y"),
 ("2010-04-10", "B", "Z"),
 ("2010-05-10", "A", "X"),
 ("2010-05-10", "A", "Y"),
 ("2010-05-10", "B", "Z"),
 ("2010-06-10", "A", "X"),
 ("2010-06-10", "B", "Z"),
 ("2010-07-10", "A", "X"),
 ("2010-07-10", "B", "Z")],
 ("date", "id1", "id2")
)
df.show()

+----------+---+---+
|      date|id1|id2|
+----------+---+---+
|2010-03-10|  A|  X|
|2010-03-10|  A|  Y|
|2010-03-10|  B|  Z|
|2010-04-10|  A|  X|
|2010-04-10|  A|  Y|
|2010-04-10|  B|  Z|
|2010-05-10|  A|  X|
|2010-05-10|  A|  Y|
|2010-05-10|  B|  Z|
|2010-06-10|  A|  X|
|2010-06-10|  B|  Z|
|2010-07-10|  A|  X|
|2010-07-10|  B|  Z|
+----------+---+---+
```

With expected output:

```
+----------+---+---+--------+
|      date|id1|id2|dup_flag|
+----------+---+---+--------+
|2010-03-10|  A|  X|       1|
|2010-03-10|  A|  Y|       1|
|2010-03-10|  B|  Z|       0|
|2010-04-10|  A|  X|       1|
|2010-04-10|  A|  Y|       1|
|2010-04-10|  B|  Z|       0|
|2010-05-10|  A|  X|       1|
|2010-05-10|  A|  Y|       1|
|2010-05-10|  B|  Z|       0|
|2010-06-10|  A|  X|       1|
|2010-06-10|  B|  Z|       0|
|2010-07-10|  A|  X|       0|
|2010-07-10|  B|  Z|       0|
+----------+---+---+--------+
```

Where `dup_flag` is a flag that indicates whether or not id1 contains a duplicate mapping to `id2` somewhere in the past 2 months.

That is, for `id1` `B`, it never maps to any other `id2` than `Z`, hence it is never flagged as a duplicate.
For `id1` `A` we do have duplicate mappings. In this example I put the window size to `2`, which means that if `A` maps to multiple `id2` within any date of a window that goes at most one month back (i.e. the current month as well as the past month should be included in the window), it should receive a flag. Hence, `A` receives this flag up until `2010-07-10`, as in this period, we have a window that consists of both `2010-06-10` and `2010-07-10`, in which `A` *does not* map to multiple `id2` (it only maps to `id2` `X` in this window).

Comment: For the row `|2010-07-10|  A|  X|       0|`, shouldn't the flag be 1 because there are duplicate entries on 2020-05-10 ?

Comment: The flag should be 0 because for a window size of `2` I would only want to look at `2010-06-10` and `2010-07-10` when the date is `2010-07-10`. `2010-05-10` in that case will be disregarded.

Comment: but you said `within any date of a window that goes at most two months back` ;)

Comment: You're right, mistake on my part. Fixed it in the text now!

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat hacky way to solve this. Essentially you create a window which is range-based instead of row-based, and do a `count distinct` over that window. Somehow Spark doesn't support the latter, so I needed to hack around it by using `size(collect_set)` which is essentially the same as `count distinct`. Also Spark doesn't support range-based windows ordered by dates, so I needed to cast the column into integer type and use a magic number 2678400 which is equal to the number of seconds in 31 days.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

### initialize df as in the question
### df = ...

df = df.withColumn('date', F.col('date').cast('timestamp').cast('bigint'))
flag = (F.size(F.collect_set(F.col('id2')).over(Window.partitionBy('id1').orderBy('date').rangeBetween(-2678400, 0))) > 1).cast('int')
df = df.withColumn('flag', flag)
df = df.withColumn('date', F.col('date').cast('timestamp').cast('date'))
```

The idea being something like

```
COUNT DISTINCT id2 OVER (PARTITION BY id1 ORDER BY date RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' MONTH PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see that the solution does not flag `2010-06-10` as a duplicate entry for `A`, even though it does have a duplicate mapping in `2010-05-10`. Perhaps this is due to the fact that not every month has exactly 30 days.

Comment: Yeah then maybe I should use 31 instead

Comment: I believe that will still cause issues given that not each month has exactly 31 days. It seems that this problem is not as trivial as I had assumed, thank you very much for helping regardless.

Comment: Ah I should have extracted the month and convert to an integer, if you're only interested in that!

Comment: But then there will be a problem of year, like '2010-01' vs '2009-12'

Comment: Yeah, so I'm trying to create this as a function that is as modular as possible, with input data ranging from daily, weekly and monthly frequency. This is what makes it especially difficult it seems.